# How can I get all objects a user has specific permissions to in django guardian?

Tags: python, django, permissions

I am currently doing a really clumsy loop over all the objects but that is going to get slow:

```
videos = Video.objects.all()
video_list = []
for video in videos:
    checker = ObjectPermissionChecker(request.user)
    if checker.has_perm('view_video', video):
        video_list.append(video)
```

I figure there must be a way of just getting all the objects for which this user has permissions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a few days ago there were update with new shortcut function called "get_objects_for_user". If you use older version of guardian and cannot update, you can simply copy codes from there.

```
from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_user
...
videos = get_objects_for_user(request.user, "view_video", Video.objects.all())
```

It always do 3 queries. If you specify "use_groups" parameter to False, then 2 queries are performed however returned queryset wouldn't contain objects for which users' groups have permissions. You may also specify list of codenames, rather than single permission if needed. [Read more here](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#std%3ashortcut-get_objects_for_user).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. Can I update with easy_install django-guardian?

Comment: Don't worry - I used pip install --upgrade which appears to have worked fine.

Comment: You can just pass Video instead of Video.objects.all so django will do one less query. Also "view_video" must be something like "app_name.view_video"

https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/check.html#get-objects-for-user

Answer (score 1):

You know that you are creating a new instance of `ObjectPermissionChecker` in each loop while you don't have to do that , and i will suggest to do something like this which can be more syntactically sugar and maybe can give you more speed

```
checker = ObjectPermissionChecker(request.user)

videos = Video.objects.all()

video_list = [video for video in videos if checker.has_perm('view_video', video)]
```

For your question you can use [django-object-permissions](http://code.osuosl.org/projects/object-permissions) look [here](http://blogs.osuosl.org/kreneskyp/2010/11/29/django-object-permissions/) for more detail about how to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed up drastically why not jus ask the database to pull only the objects you're interested in,

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Video)
perm = Permissions.objects.get(codename='view_video'.split('.')[-1])

objs = set(
    UserObjectPermissions.objects.filter(user=user, permission=perm, content_type=content_type)
)

# and if you want to include groups
objs.update(
    set(
         GroupObjectPermissions.objects.filter(group__user=user, permission=perm, content_type=content_type)
    )
)
```

This should get you all user objects which the user has permission to through both their user and group.