# Django user filtering

Tags: django, authentication

I want to be able to efficiently find all user with a particular permission and then among those users find all users who have a particular flag (I extended the base `User` model and created my own, which has the flag). I was wondering what is the easiest/efficient way to do this? I was reading the below (among other sites):

[How can I get all objects a user has specific permissions to in django guardian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663694/how-can-i-get-all-objects-a-user-has-specific-permissions-to-in-django-guardian)

But they dont seem to be helping in my situation. Please let me know if there is an article I missed, thanks!

**[EDIT]**

I read the following page:

http://digitaldreamer.net/blog/2010/5/10/get-all-users-group-django/

Basically I want to get all users who have a particular permission AND who have a certain flag. Right now I can do: `User.objects.filter(organization_id = id)` to get all users within a particular `organization` as per my code. But within that list, I want all users who have a particular permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as mentioned above. But by chaining filter statements, it is also possible. I referred to this other question: [How to get a list of all users with a specific permission group in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378303/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-users-with-a-specific-permission-group-in-django). By chaining both filter statements, I can get all users with a permission and all users with the certain `organization_id`.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a question related to django-guardian and answered it myself after much research. I believe you should be able to find your answer here: [Django Groups and Permissions. Extending Groups to have a FK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095296/django-groups-and-permissions-extending-groups-to-have-a-fk/11325519#11325519)

**UPDATE**

You could do something like this:

```
user_list = []
for user in User.Objects.filter(organization_id=id):
    if user.has_perm('PERM NAME'):
        user_list.append(user)
```

See this link for more details: http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/userguide/check.html

Comment: Not sure if I am misunderstanding what you have written there...but I dont think it's for the same purpose I'm trying to solve? I updated my question.